# Increase the data size

Tags: python, file

I have a sample of data with the below given format. I need to increase the size of data to about 100 million entries. The sequence of the rows does not matter would be better a random row sequence.

Input

```
004096f41eb8 00904bf131ad 40.0 820219 438869 820219 438869
004096f41eb8 00904bf469bd 40.0 820219 438869 820219 438869
00022d56dffe 00022dcbe817 962.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00306511e9e0 540.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904b21787a 4250.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904b3b845a 1117.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904bc3be80 1117.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904bcd5f00 4250.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
00022dcbe817 00904bfebc7c 3737.0 820353 439280 820353 439280
```

How to increase the size of data (100 million rows manually it is not possible). Tried finding some relevant samples couldn't get any. Any useful suggestion or reference would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the size of data"?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous at best.  Please rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From how you write, I think **you're trying to figure out how to generate random data for testing (or similar) purposes**.

That being said, looking at the types of the sample data you supplied you want to generate, it looks like the following:

```
<hexadecimal> <hexadecimal> <float> <int> <int> <int> <int>
```

with the constraints that the hexadecimal has leading zeroes up to 12 digits, and the float has to be unit-sized.

However, if the above is true then to generate data of this type you can do something along this line of reasoning **(a note of warning, this is a naive attempt!)**:

```
def generate_random_data():
   hex1 = '%012X' % random.randint(0,10000000000)
   hex2 = '%012X' % random.randint(0,10000000000)
   flt = float(random.randint(0,100000)) # change this value as required
   int1 = random.randint(0,1000000) 
   int2 = random.randint(0,1000000) 
   int3 = random.randint(0,1000000) 
   int4 = random.randint(0,1000000) 

   s = '%s %s %.1f %d %d %d %d' % (hex1.lower(), \
                                   hex2.lower(), \
                                   flt, \
                                   int1, \
                                   int2, \
                                   int3, \
                                   int4)
   return s

def generate_random_data_strings(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        print generate_random_data()
```

If this correct, then simply adapt for up to the number of values you want, and write that to a file. **However, given the data you supplied I can't make a reasonable argument about the max value of your values - so change that as necessary.**

EXAMPLE RUN

```
generate_random_data_strings(7)
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
00005f8e93fc 000168ed5d44 9604.0 551625 674203 912016 143600
0000c104ecfa 0000f470720a 88605.0 636828 692739 388774 748867
00021f833e47 00001fad166f 45388.0 841076 93054 373244 356865
0001d8fe8c3c 0000f70e0e61 48101.0 566598 800563 978234 141179
000157f0f23a 00018bf2db0e 24763.0 485468 138221 722335 256191
000097d60fe9 0001550f6640 27414.0 153090 3736 761677 656677
0000675efc87 00003458055a 98721.0 736265 565842 697767 521413
```

EDIT (To generate additional columns of Latitude and Longitude)

add the following (and indent correctly) beneath `int4`:

```
longitude = random.random() * math.pi * 2
latitude = math.acos(random.random() * 2 - 1)
```

then modify `s` to this (and insert the latitude and longitude at the end of the arguments inserted, and use this as a reference for precision http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees):

```
'%s %s %.1f %d %d %d %d %.6f %.6f'
```

Comment: You are awesome ..!! Thank you so much .  This is something exactly what I was looking for ..seriously didnt know how to put in proper words.. but a little more to add. How can also include latitude and longitude in the same.

Comment: @SitzBlogz: Do you mean putting latitude and longitude as extra columns?

Comment: You are a saver ... I have been searching like hell for this ..had no idea what to exactly search for. Thank again ..

Comment: @SitzBlogz: no prob! Happy to be of service, and thank you as well! :-)

Comment: I have one query ..can we have latitude and longitude (random generations) from one geo location ..may be of only one city limits ??

Comment: @SitzBlogz: yes. Please see this post for more: http://hadoopguru.blogspot.com/2014/12/python-generate-random-latitude-and.html Good luck! :-)